# How can I skip all middlewares from the another middleware?

Tags: laravel

Have a bunch of routes and have simple permission system, so if a request was made by an admin he/she can get access to the any route without any additional conditions, so I check if a user is admin and if so I'll skip all next middlewares:

```
class IsAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (\Auth::user() && (\Auth::user()->group->name == 'admin')) {
            // skip next middlewares and give access for the route to the user
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

So problem only with `skip` part, is there any way to do so?

Comment: one solution it could be to set the app environment to testing to disable middleware...

Comment: maybe i'm not understanding your question correct, but if you want a user to acces a certain route, just don't add the IsAdmin middleware to that route?

Comment: No, thing is, an admin has full access to any route and there is middleware on the several routes that not allow the admin to proceed to the route so I need to skip the remained middlewares, so no need to repeat the code for admin check for each existing middlewares

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution could be to add this to your controller constructor.

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (\Auth::user() && (\Auth::user()->group->name == 'admin')) {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['yourControllerMethod', 'anotherControllerMethod']]);
    }
}
```